# How to protect default Zuul endpoints?

Tags: spring, api, security, cloud, netflix-zuul

I am investigating the possibility of using Zuul (Spring Cloud) as an Edge Proxy in front of a set of backend APIs.

Zuul offers some default endpoints for monitoring and administration purposes. I wonder what is the best way to protect these endpoints from public access. Ideally I only want to allow access to those endpoints from internal hosts on which, for example, monitoring tools are running.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Outh2 as end point security. In my project I use below dependancy

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and you have to give outh2 server location in yml file like below.

```
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      user-info-uri: http://localhost:8081/user
```

additionally you can follow this [video](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=video&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi5t8ztv9PRAhVIOY8KHWXBCEIQtwIIIzAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D5q8B6lYhFvE&usg=AFQjCNE6ZAC-xwFeujtW7aHW71B0Iz4dgw&sig2=67qDP_C1knyUIgOoEGnV-w&bvm=bv.144224172,d.c2I).

Answer (score 0):

I understand your proposed solution. But is this also meant to secure the default endpoints, such as \routes etc But also the actuator endpoints \health \metric & \env for example.

- Tom

Comment: Hmm easier is to use the management.port setting to enforce that all management endpoints are only accessible on a dedicated port protected from public access

Answer (score 0):

I think we will use a simple reverse proxy that listens on a different port in front of each zuul instance to only expose the URL paths that we want to expose. Public traffic should only be allowed via the reverse proxy port.